# ordering function in Fortran

Tags: list, sorting, fortran, fortran90, lib

Is there a Fortran library which has an implementation of an **ordering function**, i.e., a function `ordering(list)` (like `Ordering[]` in *Mathematica*) which gives the positions in `list` at which each successive element of the *sorted list* appears?

I can implement it but I don't want to reinvent the wheel (and my wheel could be far from perfect...). Since it is so basic I was searching for a lib containing such list operations but failed to find one.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: **Questions asking us to** recommend or **find** a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: My solution is very simple since I have only 3 elements. I thought about larger lists. Can you recommend a platform which is more suitable for such a question?

Comment: comp.lang.fortran is open to various discussions, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is for recommendatioins, but may not have Fortran people

Comment: You are looking for the subroutine `indexx.f90` in Numerical Recipes in Fortran by Press et al. 1992.

Comment: @King: great hint, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since I had this already implemented a long time ago (which relies on and borrows heavily from the Numerical Recipes book of Bill Press et al), here is a self-contained implementation of it in Fortran:

```
module index_mod
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK=>int32, RK=>real64
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine indexArrayReal(n,Array,Index)
        implicit none
        integer(IK), intent(in)  :: n
        real(RK)   , intent(in)  :: Array(n)
        integer(IK), intent(out) :: Index(n)
        integer(IK), parameter   :: nn=15, nstack=50
        integer(IK)              :: k,i,j,indext,jstack,l,r
        integer(IK)              :: istack(nstack)
        real(RK)                 :: a
        do j = 1,n
            Index(j) = j
        end do
        jstack=0
        l=1
        r=n
        do
            if (r-l < nn) then
                do j=l+1,r
                    indext=Index(j)
                    a=Array(indext)
                    do i=j-1,l,-1
                        if (Array(Index(i)) <= a) exit
                        Index(i+1)=Index(i)
                    end do
                    Index(i+1)=indext
                end do
                if (jstack == 0) return
                r=istack(jstack)
                l=istack(jstack-1)
                jstack=jstack-2
            else
                k=(l+r)/2
                call swap(Index(k),Index(l+1))
                call exchangeIndex(Index(l),Index(r))
                call exchangeIndex(Index(l+1),Index(r))
                call exchangeIndex(Index(l),Index(l+1))
                i=l+1
                j=r
                indext=Index(l+1)
                a=Array(indext)
                do
                    do
                        i=i+1
                        if (Array(Index(i)) >= a) exit
                    end do
                    do
                        j=j-1
                        if (Array(Index(j)) <= a) exit
                    end do
                    if (j < i) exit
                    call swap(Index(i),Index(j))
                end do
                Index(l+1)=Index(j)
                Index(j)=indext
                jstack=jstack+2
                if (jstack > nstack) then
                    write(*,*) 'NSTACK too small in indexArrayReal()'   ! xxx
                    error stop
                end if
                if (r-i+1 >= j-l) then
                    istack(jstack)=r
                    istack(jstack-1)=i
                    r=j-1
                else
                    istack(jstack)=j-1
                    istack(jstack-1)=l
                    l=i
                end if
            end if
        end do
    contains
        subroutine exchangeIndex(i,j)
            integer(IK), intent(inout) :: i,j
            integer(IK)                :: swp
            if (Array(j) < Array(i)) then
                swp=i
                i=j
                j=swp
            end if
        end subroutine exchangeIndex
        pure elemental subroutine swap(a,b)
            implicit none
            integer(IK), intent(inout) :: a,b
            integer(IK) :: dum
            dum=a
            a=b
            b=dum
        end subroutine swap
    end subroutine indexArrayReal
end module Index_mod

program Index_prog
    use Index_mod, only: IK, RK, indexArrayReal
    implicit none
    integer(IK), parameter  :: n = 5
    integer(IK)             :: Index(n)
    real(RK)                :: Array(n) = [ 1.,3.,4.,2.,-1. ]
    call indexArrayReal(n,Array,Index)
    write(*,*) "Index: ", Index
    write(*,*) "Array(Index): ", Array(Index)
end program Index_prog
```

Compiled with GFortran 2008, here is the output:

```
$gfortran -std=f2008 *.f95 -o main
$main
 Index:            5           1           4           2           3
 Array(Index):   -1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000            2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000
```

The above routine was for sorting real-valued arrays. To sort integer arrays, simply change `real(RK) :: Array(n)` in the interface of `subroutine indexArrayReal()` to `integer(IK) :: Array(n)`.